# SQL Server query (update grouping by?)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got the following tables to work with.(Just a sample)

**thead**

```
id      date
------------------
2399    01/01/2017
2400    18/07/2017
2300    11/11/2016
...
```

**tstocks**

```
id      product_id  type    stockq  result    
--------------------------------------------
2399    0000001       1        5    
2399    0000001       2       10
2399    0000002       1       15    
2399    0000002       2        2
2400    0000001       1        4
2400    0000001       2        6
2300    0000003       1        0
2300    0000003       2        5
```

Each product_id has 2 values, type 1 and type2. thead holds the id and the date.

I need to update result, where stockq type is 1 for each group of product_id,  where the date of tproducts.id is '01/01/2017'

So it should end up with something like this:

**tstocks**:

```
id     product_id  type   stockq    result  
--------------------------------------------
2399    0000001     1        5      15
2399    0000001     2       10
2399    0000002     1       15      17
2399    0000002     2        2
2400    0000001     1        4
2400    0000001     2        6
2300    0000003     1        0
2300    0000003     2        5
```

I tried with the following query but it says with an more than one value on the subquery error.

```
update tstocks
set result = (select sum(stockq) 
              from tstocks 
              group by tstocks.product_id) 
from tstocks
inner join thead ON tstocks.id = thead.id
where tstocks.type = '1' and thead.date = '01/01/2017'
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where tstocks.type='1'

Comment: Where do the 15 and 17 come from?

Comment: What is the table structure for thead and tstocks ?  What are the primary keys ?

Comment: @Amit Thanks, just a typo :p

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is the result of adding both stockq values for each.

Comment: @AmirPelled both id fields on each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an updatable CTE and window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select s.*, sum(stockq) over (partition by id, product_id) as new_result
      from tstocks
     )
update toupdate
    set result = new_result
    from toupdate join
         thead
         on toupdate.id = thead.id
    where thead.date = '2017-01-01' and toupdate.type = 1;
```

Note that I changed the date to a standard format and dropped the single quotes around the type.  This assumes the columns have the types of `date`/`datetime` and number respectively.

You can also follow your reasoning, but with a *correlated* subquery:

```
update s
    set result = (select sum(s2.stockq)
                  from tstocks s2
                  where s2.product_id = s.product_id an s2.id = s.id
                 ) 
    from tstocks s inner join
         thead h
         on s.id = h.id
    where s.stockq = 1 and h.date = '2017-01-01';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. Worked like a charm.